# 'gets' accepts uppercase or lowercase

Tags: ruby

I want to allow the user to input a choice given in my CLI using `gets` in either uppercase or lowercase. For example:

```
puts "please type info for more details"
```

How can I accomplish this task?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow Danny, please elaborate and edit your question correctly as it's very generalistic. Follow this guidelines https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: The piece of code you provided is nothing. It is not even a step toward what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
gets.downcase
```

and then assign it to the variable

Comment: Hey ! Petr Balaban

Comment: Thank you for you help. Such a simple but yet effective solution.

Comment: @danny: If then answer helped you, then please mark it as the correct answer to reward the effort of the person who helped you. ;-)